# Using Quarkus OpenId Connect and Azure b2c

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, quarkus

I'm building a backend-service that provides an API using Quarkus and I need to validate the incoming requests.
By default, quarkus uses keycload, but I want to validate with azure b2c.

At the moment I have the following configs:

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p={policy}
quarkus.oidc.application.application-type=service
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.paths=/hello/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.policy=authenticated
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.oidc".level= DEBUG
```

And as an example:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @RolesAllowed("test")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello RESTEasy";
    }
```

But Quarkus keeps throwing the same error:

```
  OIDC server is not available at the 'https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p={policy}'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. 

Policy name for Azure AD B2C, format is like

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

(or)

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-id> /<policy-name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

> The code in your Azure AD B2C-enabled applications and APIs may refer
> to login.microsoftonline.com in several places. For example, your code
> might have references to user flows and token endpoints. Update the
> following to instead reference **your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com**:
>
> 1. Authorization endpoint
> 2. Token endpoint
> 3. Token issuer

Please do check this [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin#change-identity-provider-redirect-urls) for more information on the same.

2.

OIDC service application needs to know OpenId Connect provider’s token,
By default they are discovered by adding a `/.well-known/openid-configuration` path to the configured quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url.

Ex: https://{tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/{tenant-id}/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={policy-name}

By default, the iss claim value is compared to the issuer property which may have been discovered in the well-known provider configuration. But if quarkus.oidc.token.issuer property is set then the iss claim value is compared to it instead.

**References:**

1. [quarkus/issues](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/13265)
2. [security-openid-connect](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect)